# Bug in voting to reopen a question

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

I know this is a really tiny bug, but it matters (at least to me).

As a user, I asked a question on Stack Overflow; then that question got closed for being a duplicate. Then, I edited it to show the difference between the two. After that, I saw a button below my question saying "reopen", and I thought it would result in an error like trying to upvote my own question, but, to my surprise, it voted!

Is this a bug or a feature? Should the user who created the question be able to vote to reopen their own question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a privilege granted at [250 rep to vote to reopen your own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).

Note that you need between 3 and 5 votes to reopen depending on the site so it just makes reopening a little easier predicated on you knowing a little about how the site works.